# Can Firebase Dynamic Links be used to attribute installations to marketing campaigns?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Firebase Dynamic links allows you to set the utm campaign parameters, however I have not been able to find a clear answer if the campaign parameters survive the installation process and are attributed.

We would like to generate our own dynamic links for non-adnetwork campaigns, e.g. posting on facebook, within edm's etc and be able to work out what campaigns are driving the most installations.

Answer (score 1):

For the campaign information to survive, you'll need to [utilize the provided fields when constructing your links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links#manually_constructing_a_url). Specifically, the "social media tag parameters" look useful in this case.

However, that info isn't going to be captured in analytics as a campaign, necessarily, and you'll either need to coax this data to generate useful reports or import it into BigQuery for more advanced analysis.